# Create IPv4 reservation with DUID in Windows Server 2012 DHCP

Tags: windows-server-2012, dhcp

Can I configure reservations for IPv4 addresses in Windows Server 2012 DHCP for systems which send DHCP requests with a DUID for their client identifier (Option 61)?

I have Linux (e.g., Fedora 21) systems on my network which send a DUID for Option 61 of the DHCP request.  When Windows DHCP receives these requests it does not use the reservations I have input for the clients (these reservations use MAC address only, because Windows does not appear to allow use of DUID for IPv4 reservations).  If I add `dhcp-client-identifier = hardware;` to /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf on the client so that it sends MAC address only for Option 61, the issue is resolved.  However, I am looking for a solution which can be applied to the server once rather than a solution which requires me to modify settings on all client systems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can!
But you have to get the client-identifier of the requesting machine and put it into the reservation field instead of the macaddress on the DHCP-Server.
This works in Windows-DHCP-Server.